# What does a Mauritian need to visit France?

Tags: france, schengen-visas, mauritian-citizens

I have a Mauritian passport and a biometric residence permit valid for 2 years. What do I need to  visit family member in France for just a week in August.

Comment: A BRP for where? The UK?  Mauritian citizens do not need a visa to enter the Schengen area as a tourist https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/docs/visa_lists_en.pdf

Comment: You need plane tickets, most probably.

Comment: The website of the French embassy in Mauritius should explain everything you need about visas. It's best to get your advice from official sources where it's available; we do our best to help but we might make mistakes. If you have a more specific question about what you've read on the French emabssy website, please do ask that!

Comment: @Traveller that sounds like an answer.  As far as I know BRP is a term used only in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Mauritian citizens do not need a visa to enter the Schengen area as a tourist for up to 90 days in a period of 180 days https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/docs/visa_lists_en.pdf

On arrival in France you must be able to show various supporting documents at the request of the Border Police, including 
a valid passport issued less than 10 years before and valid for at least 3 months after the envisaged departure date, proof of accommodation covering the whole duration of the stay, 
sufficient financial means, and return ticket or the financial means to acquire one at the envisaged return date. https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas/que-faire-apres-mon-arrivee-en-france

Comment: The ticket out of the Schengen area does not need to be to the same location as you started out from but it needs to be to a place where you are guarantied entrance.